# jQuery - Change vertical menu to horizontal

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to use the Tendina jQuery Plugin. It works great, but I'd like the menus to be laid out horizontally, like this:

[image]

I've been messing around with the CSS ( `inline-block` and other stuff ) but haven't been able to make it work.

I'm not gonna post the JS because it's a whole lot of code... I think too much to paste here, but feel free to check the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vf7adn54/).

Any help would be highly appreciated.
Thanks.

HTML

```
<ul class="dropdown">
  <li>
    <a href="#">Menu 1</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Submenu 1</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Menu 2</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Submenu 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Submenu 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Submenu w/ children</a>
        <ul>
          <li>Subsubmenu 2</li>
          <li>Subsubmenu 2</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Menu 3</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Submenu 3</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Submenu 3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
.dropdown {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #f7f7f7;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    padding-top: 20px;
    font-size: 12px;
}

.dropdown li {
   padding: 0 10px;
}

.dropdown li.selected {
    background-color: #f2f2f2;
}

.dropdown li a {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 10px;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: black;
}

.dropdown li > ul li {
    padding: 0 20px;
}

.dropdown li > ul li a {
    color: gray;
}

.dropdown li > ul li > ul li {
    padding: 10px 30px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an updated version of your [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vf7adn54/2/)

```
    .dropdown
    {
      position:absolute;
      left:0;
      top:0;
      height:100%;
      width:100%;
      background-color:#f7f7f7;
      font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
      padding-top:20px;
      font-size:12px
    }

    .dropdown li
    {
      padding:0 10px;
      display:inline-block;
      width:auto
    }

    .dropdown li.selected
    {
      background-color:#f2f2f2
    }

    .dropdown li a
    {
      display:block;
      width:100%;
      padding:10px;
      text-decoration:none;
      text-transform:uppercase;
      color:#000
    }

    .dropdown ul
    {
      position:absolute
    }

    .dropdown li > ul li
    {
      padding:10px 0;
    }

    .dropdown li > ul li a
    {
      color:gray
    }

    .dropdown li > ul li > ul li
    {
      padding:10px 30px
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks but the Submenus and Subsubmenus should also be laid out horizontally like the main menu. I mean, sliding down like they are now (that part is just as it is) but horizontally, not as a vertical list. Please see the picture I posted.

Comment: I've updated my fiddle, removed `display: block` for childs list element.

Comment: I forgot about the 3rd level submenus, you can set your `.dropdown ul { width: 100%;` }

Comment: Okay, got it! What about making them all align to the left?

Comment: Add `left: 0` in you `.dropdown ul` rule

Comment: @ it does align everything to the left, but the submenus and subsubmenus turn vertical again... :(

Comment: My bad, I was adding it to the wrong fiddle. Thanks.